# Random RSS Data

Tags: java, android

I'm kind of new to android so please bear with me.

I need help with something, I have a rss feed that has energy tips in it. Instead of displaying all of them inside a listview I would like to display them one at a time on an activity that has a timer that automatically switches them inside a textview this activity would also have two buttons "prev" and "next" which would override the timer. Is it possible?  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you give me pointers on where to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the kind of view you might be looking for is a [ViewSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html).  This will allow you to switch and animate between different views in your app.  While you can imagine more elaborate configurations (really, anything), this might be a good choice to you that's already baked into the framework.  How to control the view is a slightly different question, however, there are multiple ViewSwitcher tutorials out there, and you can easily implement a Timer which switches between the views.  What you do is fairly simple: tell the timer to fire after some interval.  If the user presses some button before the timer fires, cancel the timer and (perhaps) reset it?